# Need a VLOOKUP formula for two similar, yet non-identical columns of data

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am working with two separate worksheets.

In the 1st worksheet I need a VLOOKUP formula that checks A2 & looks for the same ID# in the 2nd sheet (also in column A2) - then it must return the data in the column to the right.

The problem is that the ID# numbers in each column of the worksheets are similar, yet different.

Here is an example of how the ID numbers appear in the first worksheet:

Column A

907677/001/1 *

907694/001/2

907694/001/3

907695/001/1

- "/1" references the number of times the ID# appears in the table
- and the 2nd worksheet (which I need to be able to pull data from)

Column A

907677/001

907694/001

907694/001

907695/001

As you can see - my problem is that in the 2nd worksheet the last part of of the string "/#" is missing - so there is no unique identifier to use to differentiate between the first appearance of an ID# and the second.

Is there anyway to add this ability to column A of the 2nd worksheet so that I can have my precious VLOOKUP and get on with the rest of my life?

Any & all help is GREATLY appreciated.

Pardon any confusion or wordiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a helper column in worksheet2.  For example in Cell B1 of Sheet2

```
=A1&"/"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1)
```

Just pull that down in Column B to create the correct form of id.